# Именованные функциональные выражения (Named Function Expression)

Tags: javascript

Что выведется в консоль при выполнении этого кода? Почему?

```
(function test() { test = 123; console.log( test ); }())
```

В консоль выведется эта функция:

```
function test() { test = 123; console.log( test ) ;}
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [этой статье](https://learn.javascript.ru/named-function-expression), перезаписать имя NPE, доступное внутри самого NPE и используемое для рекурсивного вызова (вместо устаревшего `arguments.callee`), нельзя.
В [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), к сожалению, про запрет переписывания ничего не сказано, однако практика (ваш пример) говорит о том, что это всё же верное утверждение.

Поэтому `test = 123;` не даёт никакого эффекта, и `console.log` выводит первоначальное значение `test` - само NPE.

Answer (score 4):

В [стандарте](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) описан процесс вычисления именованного функционального выражения

Внутри тела имя функционального выражения будет являться *immutable binding* и при включенном [*Strict Mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) при попытке изменить его будет ошибка времени выполнения.

Так как у вас не используется *"use strict";* [*Strict Mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) выключен и присваивание просто игнорируется.

Чтобы на консоль вывелось ожидаемое значение необходимо объявить *test* локально с помощью ключевого слова *var*

```js
(function test() { var test = 123; console.log( test ); }())
```

Comment: Я вчера ночью уже был не в состоянии искать в спецификации ECMAScript. Меня вот что поставило в тупик в этом вопросе: если определить локальную переменную `test` (как это сделано в вашем примере), то как после этого обращаться к функции?

Comment: @Regent, никак :-)

Comment: Весьма прискорбно :) Понятно, что, по уму, просто не надо создавать переменную с таким именем, но на какой-нибудь хитрый выход из такого положения (`arguments.callee` не в счет) я всё же надеялся.